# Is it possible to update using hql without subquery..?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

for example(Assume all annotation is at place, or suggest if any you have updated one):-

```
class Student{
      int id;
      Subject sub;
    /*Getter Setter*/
}
class Subject{
      int marks;
    /*Getter Setter*/
}
```

Can I write HQL query like(I'm trying this but not woring) :-

```
Update Student s set s.sub.marks = 10 where s.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported.

You have to use the subquery:

```
update Subject s set s.marks = 10
where s.id in (select sub.id from Student where id = 1)
```